# Custom taxonomy list page?

Tags: taxonomy

I'm working on a restaurant site, and I have a custom post type for dishes, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'=> $labels,
    'public'=> true,
    'publicly_queryable'=>true,
    'show_ui'=>true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'=>true,
    'query_var'=>'dish',
    'rewrite'=>true,
    'capability_type'=>'post',
    'hierarchicial'=>false,
    'menu_position'=>5,
    'supports'=>array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        'custom-fields',
        'revisions'
    )   
);  

register_post_type('dish', $args);
```

An example of one of the custom taxonomies I want to use is this:

```
register_taxonomy('Main Ingredient', array('dish'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Main Ingredient',
    'singular_label' => 'Main Ingredient',
    'query_var'=>true,
    'rewrite' => true)
);
```

The custom taxonomies are working fine in the admin, and I can go to `myurl.com/main-ingredient/pork` and see a list of all dishes with pork in them.

What I'm wanting to do is be able to hit `myurl.com/main-ingredient` and get a list of all the various main-ingredient values.

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/custom-taxonomy-listing-page-when-no-term-set-all-terms) reference, which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

But the solution is not working for me - I'm still getting a 404 when going to `myurl.com/main-ingredient`

Any suggestions on how best to do this?

Answer (score 20):

There is nothing built-in to WordPress to provide an *"index"* page for your taxonomy as your question implies there should be *(and I agree, there should be! But there isn't.)*

Instead you have to hack it and one way to do that is to create a page called *"Main Ingredient"* with a `main-ingredient` URL slug and assign it [**a page template for your theme that you will create**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) *(maybe)* called *"Main Ingredient List"*:

[image: Screenshot showing where to set Page Template in WordPress]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110130-012512.png))</sub>

Here's a starting point; maybe use the file name `page-main-ingredient-list.php`  for your page template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Main Ingredient List
*/
get_header();
$main_ingredients = get_terms('main-ingredient');
foreach($main_ingredients as $main_ingredient) {
  $dishes = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'dish',
    'post_per_page'=>-1,
    'taxonomy'=>'main-ingredient',
    'term' => $main_ingredient->slug,
  ));
  $link = get_term_link(intval($main_ingredient->term_id),'main-ingredient');
  echo "<h2><a href=\"{$link}\">{$main_ingredient->name}</a></h2>";
  echo '<ul>';
  while ( $dishes->have_posts() ) {
    $dishes->the_post();
    $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo "<li><a href=\"{$link}\">{$title}</a></li>";
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
get_footer();
```

And then here's what the page looks like with some dummy data on my test site:

[image: Screenshot of a Taxonomy Index page for a WordPress Site]

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I did do that. It doesn't help.

Comment: @Josh - I added [the code you find here](https://gist.github.com/e4cafd98069a5304111e) to my theme's `functions.php` file and then went to `http://wp30.dev/main-ingredient/chicken/` *(`wp30.dev` is my local test site)* and got [this screenshot](http://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110130-003228.png).  So if it's not working you have some plugin or some other code that is causing it not to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. That does work for me, but is not the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to get a listing of the main ingredients by going to the top level of the taxonomy. In other words, if you eliminate "chicken" from your URL, you should get a 404 page. That's the problem I'm running into.

Comment: @Josh - Okay, I see that now. Sorry, I've been answering too many questions today. FYI, there is nothing "built-in" way in WordPress to handle what you are asking for. It would make lots of sense for it to be there automatically, but currently it is not. I'll write an update which is a workaround.

Comment: Great, thanks - looking forward to putting this one behind me. ;-)

Comment: @Josh - I think my updated answer will make more sense to you.

Comment: Yeah, I had thought about doing that already, but I hate losing the great built-in functionality of the post viewing and navigation via taxonomy term. Thanks for the replies, though. 

Hopefully WP adds that taxonomy index functionality soon.

Comment: @Josh - *"but I hate losing the great built-in functionality of the post viewing and navigation via taxonomy term":* I must be missing something because I don't see how you loose anything with this?

Comment: @Jan - Done. :)

Comment: I figured I'd do this as a last resort in a custom taxonomy project I'm working on (I'd rather not clutter my client's Pages listing with a bunch of empty pages), but finding no other answers, figure this is still the only way to accomplish a task similar to the original poster's. Mike, know if they've updated this in recent versions?

Comment: @aendrew - *"Mike, know if they've updated this in recent versions?"* Sorry but I'm not following the context of your question. Maybe best to **[ask a new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)**?

Comment: I would just like to point out that the question askee is using an invalid name for the register_taxonomy function, the name of the taxonomy is to be all lowercase and have no spaces as per the documentation which states: "The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces)." old question, but something to be aware of if you're using this questions advice and code for any projects.