# Create an archive page for custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I switched my site from categories to taxonomies for my custom post but I am having trouble getting it to work the same way.  For categories I could have templates named something like `category-travel.php` and then have my loop in that file.  Now I am trying to replace the category list with something like this :

```
<?php  
$taxonomy = 'Gallery';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0;
$pad_counts = 0;
$hierarchical = 1;
$title = '';

$args = array (
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title
    );

wp_list_categories($args) ?>
```

and in functions

```
register_taxonomy( 'Gallery', array( 'photo' ), array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Galleries', 'singular_label' => 'Gallery', 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

Now when I link from that generated list, something like `mysite.com/gallery/name` it is instead calling the `archive.php` rather than the `taxonomy-gallery.php` file I created.  What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if this is [a duplicate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/custom-taxonomy-list-page) but I think that question is for something different and I cant believe that you would have to do a hack for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your issue is the name of your taxonomy has a capital letter, the first argument of register_taxonomy is to be all lowercase, no spaces as the documentation for the register_taxonomy function mentions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Change your code to the following and your taxonomy-gallery.php template will work correctly.

```
register_taxonomy( 'gallery', array( 'photo' ), array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Galleries', 'singular_label' => 'Gallery', 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

In the first bit of code you posted, you will also want to change the reference to the gallery taxonomy to be lowercase as well. Labels are fine with any case, but not actual names of taxonomies.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I had that page open one tab over but obviously did not read it very carefully.   Appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries man. Simple things like that always happen to the best of us, I've been tricked up like that many times.