# How do I provide a "show all posts" link in a paginated term archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, terms

I have a custom post type called `game_go` and a taxonomy called `game_go_series`. Some example terms are `chase` , `compete`, `victory`, etc. I have a file called `taxonomy-game_go_series` which displays only the posts in paginated form of an *individual* term.

The second page I want to create needs to show *all* that individual term's posts. In other words, there would be two pages that have the same term.

Also, and this is important, I know how to do this by using the term in the filename (e.g. `taxonomy-game_go-chase.php`), but since we'll be adding more terms, it'll become a pain to have to create a template file each time.

Is there a way to do this where pages by term-taxonomy are created automatically when we add new terms?

Let me know if I can provide further clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I would note that this question implies the filename determines the content, when it's actually the other way around, the content is retrieved long before WP knows which template to load. Instead, would it not make more sense to ask about your original problem? AKA **"How do I provide a show all posts link in a paginated term archive?"**, this is a classic XY problem

Comment: So to make more clear, the only difference between your first and second archive is that the first displays posts with pagination and the second have to show them all without pagination?

Comment: @ClemC exactly! I'm not sure how to create two new pages that show the same individual term's post

Comment: @TomJNowell well put! I updated the main subject line and that's essentially what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind is that if there are a lot of posts to show, then bad things can happen, there's only so much time and memory to load up the posts, and if there are hundreds of thousands it can grind to a halt

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/custom-taxonomy-listing-page-when-no-term-set-all-terms Check it out

Answer (score 1):

This method will set it up so that if you add /all to the end of your taxonomy archives, it will show all posts.

First, when registering the taxonomy, make sure you set the `ep_mask` to `EP_CATEGORIES`. This means we can add a custom endpoint to it.

```
function wpse_277843_register_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'game_go_series', 'game_go', array(
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'    => 'series',
            'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES,
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_277843_register_taxonomy' );
```

Don't copy all that code, just make sure you do the `ep_mask` thing in your code, because it's probably not already set that way.

To add `ep_mask` to Custom Post Types UI generated taxonomies, do this:

```
function wpse_277843_cptui_ep_mask( $args, $taxonomy_slug, $taxonomy_args ) {
    if ( 'game_go_series' == $taxonomy_slug ) {
        $args['rewrite']['ep_mask'] = EP_CATEGORIES;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'cptui_pre_register_taxonomy', 'wpse_277843_cptui_ep_mask', 10, 3 );
```

Then create the `all` rewrite endpoint to the `EP_CATEGORIES` mask.

```
function wpse_277843_all_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'all', EP_CATEGORIES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_277843_all_endpoint' );
```

This does mean that the endpoint will also be valid for Categories, but we can ignore them for any custom behaviour later. Unfortunately adding endpoints only to a custom taxonomy appears to be impossible right now. It just means that going to `/category/category-name/all` won't throw a 404. The `/all` will just be ignored (or you can apply the same behaviour for categories, if you want).

Then, in `pre_get_posts`, if the `all` endpoint is accessed on your custom taxonomy, set `posts_per_page` to `-1`:

```
function wpse_277843_all_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax( 'game_go_series' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['all'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_277843_all_posts' );
```

Then you can add a link to your template to the /all version, if you're on a taxonomy archive already, and if it's not already the /all version:

```
<?php if ( is_tax( 'game_go_series' ) && get_query_var( 'all', false ) === false ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( get_queried_object() ); ?>all/">
        Show All
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for all this!! After looking over it, it looks like you definitely understand my problem and your answer all makes sense but do you by any chance know if I can "inject" that `ep_mask` parameter into my taxonomy which is being generated from the CPT UI Plugin? I could copy the generated code for the taxonomy into my functions.php but want to avoid this as I have tons of other taxonomies generated from the plugin.

Comment: Updated my answer with some code based on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-insert-ep_mask-argument-for-custom-taxonomies/

Comment: Actually, it looks like `ep_masks` is being set to an integer. Is that normal?

Comment: EP_CATEGORIES is an integer, so yes that's right, is this not working?

Comment: Nah unfortunately not...keeps returning a 404 error when I navigate to the /all page.